# alternative to regex pattern foreach value in array Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am checking a regex pattern against each line of STDIN foreach value in an array.
I am using the value in the array in the regex pattern. So the example below should match any row that has one of the three numbers in @nums followed by 6 more digits.

```
my @nums = qw/
    509
    544
    555
/;

while(my $line = <>) {
    chomp $line;
    foreach my $num (@nums) {
        if ($line =~ /$num\d{6}/) {
            say $line;
        }
    }
}
```

input

```
504333322
544009113
509323232
1509868333333
443123432
509999
5599234
410987655
```

output

```
544009113
509323232
1509868333333
```

This is working fine for me, but I would like to know, in order to increase performance, if there is way to do the same thing without the repeated regex matching.

Thank You.

Comment: We dunno what is `$row[2]`

Comment: Sorry typo. I fixed it.

Comment: Your code is only reading each line of STDIN once. I assume it is the repeated regex matching you want to avoid? Are all the numbers in @nums of 3 digits?

Comment: And you realize that this will match also numbers like `10509123456` (`509` followed by 6 numbers in the middle), and you are okay with that? (I.e. partial matches)

Comment: @harmic yes I suppose you are right, It is the repeated regex matching Id like to avoid.

Comment: @TLP yes that is fine. Id just like to avoid the repeated regex matching.

Comment: @BryanK `my $nums = join "|", @nums; my $rx = qr($nums\d{6})` perhaps

Comment: To better specify the problem:
 1. Is it performance you are concerned about (concise / eloquent seems more about how the code reads)
 2. Can we assume anything about the numbers in @nums? Are they all a fixed number of digts
 3. Can we assuming anything about the input lines? As per @BryanK comment your current code matches anywhere in the line which is a wide search

Comment: @harmic I see your point, it is about the performance. The numbers in `@nums` and the input are arbitrary really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following--a variation of [TLP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/725418/tlp)'s in a comment above--creates a positive lookbehind of alternations using the values in `@nums`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @nums = qw/
  509
  544
  555
  /;

my $ORnums = '(?<=' . ( join '|', @nums ) . ')';
my $regex  = qr/$ORnums\d{6}/;

while (<DATA>) {
    print if /$regex/;
}

__DATA__
504333322
544009113
509323232
1509868333333
443123432
509999
5599234
410987655
```

Output:

```
544009113
509323232
1509868333333
```

Hope this helps!